# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am getting a error

```
error_log: Could not set cookie. Headers already sent.
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) link URL is not properly formatted thrown in /home/admin/facebook.php on line 453
```

The script worked a months ago so just uploaded it again and got a error. This is a custom built script so donno whats wrong so thought id ask here.  Here is my code

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
require_once 'database.class.php';
require_once 'config.php';

/**
 * FB Session
 */
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
    'secret' => FB_SECRET,
    'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$params = array(
    'canvas'        => 1,
    'fbconnect'     => 0,
    'next'          => URL_CANVAS,
    'req_perms'     => 'publish_stream, offline_access'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

/**
 * User authenticated?
 */
if ($session) {
    try {
        $fb_uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me     = $facebook->api('/me');
        $access_token = $session['access_token'];
        $pg     = 'main';
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "' . URL_CANVAS . '";</script>';
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $pg = 'splash';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0" />

        <title>bloxorz worldst hardest game can you beat it ?</title>

        <!--// using jQuery UI for this sample app //-->
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
<!--// Facebook Javascript SDK needed for IFrame Canvas App //-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '<?php echo FB_APP_ID; ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>

<!--// START: page include //-->
<?php
if (!empty($pg)) { 
    include $pg . '.php'; 
} else {
    echo '<b>Error:</b> Page Not Found.';
}
?>
<!--// END: page include //-->
```

or is the error in side the facebook.php page ?
Because the line 453 in facebook.php is

```
 // results are returned, errors are thrown
    if (is_array($result) && isset($result['error'])) {
      $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
      if ($e->getType() === 'OAuthException') {
        $this->setSession(null);
      }
      throw $e;
    }
    return $result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have started "echoing" output before headers are being set. Facebook.php on line 453 is trying to set some response headers but it can't, because headers have already been set and body of response has started.

Make sure you don't `echo`, `var_dump`, `pr` or output anything to browser before line 453 is executed.